# How to compare a String with an Array's any item in android

Tags: android, string, arraylist, switch-statement

Suppose, I have a **String** named **dogsStatus**.

```
String dogsStatus = "Dogs are running";
```

I have also an **Array**  named **dogsChoice**.

```
ArrayList<String> dogsChoice = new ArrayList<>();
dogsChoice.add("barking");
dogsChoice.add("running");
dogsChoice.add("eating");
```

Now, I want to setup a **SWITCH-CASE** with the **String dogsStatus** .

So please see the code if it is ever possible or not:-

```
switch(dogsStatus){
       case "Dogs are" + dogsChoice:
       //Do something
         }
```

If it is not possible then is there any way to compare a String with an array's any value? Not any specific one...

Comment: you want Dogs are running, Dogs are barking etc. right?

Comment: Actually, the items are presented in the array is not specified. It will very different on various devices. Those items are examples only. I want to compare string with any value of a given array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...........

```
for(int=0; i<dogsChoice.size();i++){
switch(dogsStatus){
       case "Dogs are" + dogsChoice[i]:
       //Do something
         }
}
```

Comment: Congratulations, Bangladesh. You did it. Thanks. Me, also from the same.

Comment: Actually, I thought it before. But, as my array items will be unlimited in the real app, so I thought, my case will be unlimited. I just rejected that idea for this reason. But, now, I think it will work...

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
dogsChoice.contains("your compare word");
```

Comment: Sir, I know that way to implement. But my problem is here the array contains three elements. And where I will use the code in the real app, there will have different elements fron device to device. Here have only three but on real device there will have so many items. So, I will have no idea. For this reason, I wanted to know if it is possible to compare a String with an array's any item...

Comment: I don/t understand your question，When your arraylist is already, 3 item or 300 item still could use "contain" to check it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Iterate your `ArrayList` and get the values

```
 for(int=0; i<dogsChoice.size();i++){

    if(dogsChoice.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("your string to be compared")){

      // do your stuff here
    }

    }
```